# Flutter Error: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2 from ProcessRecord

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-packages

I needed to import contacts from mobile, and I used [contacts_service](https://pub.dev/packages/contacts_service) from [pub.dev](https://pub.dev/). Then I made the changes required in `AndroidManifest.xml` for android and in `info.plist` for iOS, i.e, added the required permission, still I am getting this error when I am trying to read contacts from phone.

```
 Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2 from ProcessRecord
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I resolved this issue, by requesting permission from the user, like this,

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getContacts();
  }

 // Function to get permission from the user
  _contactsPermissions() async {
    PermissionStatus permission = await Permission.contacts.status;
    if (permission != PermissionStatus.granted && permission != PermissionStatus.denied) {
      Map<Permission, PermissionStatus> permissionStatus = await [Permission.contacts].request();
      return permissionStatus[Permission.contacts] ?? PermissionStatus.undetermined;
    } else {
      return permission;
    }
  }

  //Function to import contacts
  getContacts() async {
    PermissionStatus contactsPermissionsStatus = await _contactsPermissions();
    if (contactsPermissionsStatus == PermissionStatus.granted) {
      List<Contact> _contacts = (await ContactsService.getContacts(withThumbnails: false)).toList();
      setState(() {
        contacts = _contacts;
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: Add this package from pub.dev, if you've not done so already: https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler